# How to acces composite elements in a data frame

Tags: r

I've created this data frame and want to access the individual elements for plotting.  But it seems I can't.  What kind of data frame did I have created and how can I access its individual elements?

```
> print(df)

   B.mean     B.conf1     B.conf2
1  0.75000000 -0.18826132  1.68826132
2  0.66666667  0.01334534  1.31998799
3  0.33333333 -0.31998799  0.98665466

> names(df)

[1] "B"

> struct(df)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ B: num [1:3, 1:3] 0.75 0.6667 0.3333 -0.1883 0.0133 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "mean" "conf1" "conf2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'B' column is a `matrix` as evident from the `str` of 'df'.  By using `do.call` with `data.frame`, it gets converted to 3 columns of a `data.frame`.

```
 do.call(data.frame, df)
```